# read data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

it is my php read database file:

```
 <?php
// read_My_Task.php


/*
 * Following code will get single task details
 * A task_detail is identified by task id (cid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["cid"])) {
    $cid = $_GET['cid'];

    // get a task from my-task table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM my_task WHERE cid = $cid");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $my_task = array();
            $my_task["cid"] = $result["cid"];
            $my_task["cus_name"] = $result["cus_name"];
            $my_task["contact_number"] = $result["contact_number"];
            $my_task["ticket_no"] = $result["ticket_no"];
            $my_task["task_detail"] = $result["task_detail"];

            // user node
            $response["my_task"] = array();

            array_push($response["my_task"], $my_task);
            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);         
             }            

        else {
            // no task found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No task found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no task found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No task found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Database have alot of data but it always display result that "{"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}"

How to display data that is saved in MySql database

Comment: Provide `cid` in your GET request

Comment: That simply says that your `cid` isn't set..

Comment: From your error it seems you simply don't have a $_GET['cid']

Comment: **WARNING!**  Your code suffers from an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should switch to [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so that you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: From where do you get that `cid` ? Post that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is at the end of your script in an `else`. If you check the corresponding `if` it is :

```
if (isset($_GET["cid"])) {
```

That means that for you this value is not set. You just need to call your script with an argument in the URL like this :

```
http://yourroot/read_My_Task.php?cid=XXX
```

Comment: It's not a correction, when you load your script your need to add  `?cid=XXX` with XXX being the id your want to see from the database